# Speeding up count of pairwise observations in R

Tags: r, performance

I have a dataset where a subset of measurements for each entry are randomly missing:

```
dat <- matrix(runif(100), nrow=10)
rownames(dat) <- letters[1:10]
colnames(dat) <- paste("time", 1:10)
dat[sample(100, 25)] <- NA
```

I am interested in calculating correlations between each row in this dataset (i.e., a-a, a-b, a-c, a-d, ...). However, I would like to exclude correlations where there are fewer than 5 pairwise non-NA observations by setting their value to NA in the resulting correlation matrix.

Currently I am doing this as follows:

```
cor <- cor(t(dat), use = 'pairwise.complete.obs')
names <- rownames(dat)
filter <- sapply(names, function(x1) sapply(names, function(x2) 
    sum(!is.na(dat[x1,]) & !is.na(dat[x2,])) < 5))
cor[filter] <- NA
```

However, this operation is very slow as the actual dataset contains >1,000 entries.

Is there way to filter cells based on the number of non-NA pairwise observations in a vectorized manner, instead of within nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of non-NA pairwise observations using matrix approach.

Let's use this data generation code. I made data larger and added more NAs.

```
nr = 1000;
nc = 900;
dat = matrix(runif(nr*nc), nrow=nr)
rownames(dat) = paste(1:nr)
colnames(dat) = paste("time", 1:nc)
dat[sample(nr*nc, nr*nc*0.9)] = NA
```

Then you filter code is taking 85 seconds

```
tic = proc.time()
names = rownames(dat)
filter = sapply(names, function(x1) sapply(names, function(x2) 
    sum(!is.na(dat[x1,]) & !is.na(dat[x2,])) < 5));
toc = proc.time();
show(toc-tic);
# 85.50 seconds
```

My version creates a matrix with values 1 for non-NAs in the original data. Then using matrix multiplication I calculate number of pairwise non-NAs. It ran in a fraction of a second.

```
tic = proc.time()
NAmat = matrix(0, nrow = nr, ncol = nc)
NAmat[ !is.na(dat) ] = 1;
filter2 = (tcrossprod(NAmat) < 5)
toc = proc.time();
show(toc-tic);
# 0.09 seconds
```

Simple check shows the results are the same:

```
all(filter == filter2)
# TRUE
```