# Speeding up linear model fitting on complete pairwise observations in large sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, performance

I have a numeric data.frame `df` with 134946 rows x 1938 columns.
99.82% of the data are `NA`.
For each pair of (distinct) columns `"P1"` and `"P2"`, I need to find which rows have non-`NA` values for both and then do some operations on those rows (linear model).

I wrote a script that does this, but it seems quite slow.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283103/speeding-up-count-of-pairwise-observations-in-r) seems to discuss a related task, but I can't immediately see if or how it can be adapted to my case.

Borrowing the example from that post:

```
set.seed(54321)
nr = 1000;
nc = 900;
dat = matrix(runif(nr*nc), nrow=nr)
rownames(dat) = paste(1:nr)
colnames(dat) = paste("time", 1:nc)
dat[sample(nr*nc, nr*nc*0.9)] = NA

df <- as.data.frame(dat)
df_ps <- names(df)
N_ps <- length(df_ps)
```

My script is:

```
tic = proc.time()

out <- do.call(rbind,sapply(1:(N_ps-1), function(i) {
  if (i/10 == floor(i/10)) {
    cat("\ni = ",i,"\n")
    toc = proc.time();
    show(toc-tic);
  }
  do.call(rbind,sapply((i+1):N_ps, function(j) {
    w <- which(complete.cases(df[,i],df[,j]))
    N <- length(w)
    if (N >= 5) {
      xw <- df[w,i]
      yw <- df[w,j]
      if ((diff(range(xw)) != 0) & (diff(range(yw)) != 0)) {
        s <- summary(lm(yw~xw))
        o <- c(i,j,N,s$adj.r.squared,s$coefficients[2],s$coefficients[4],s$coefficients[8],s$coefficients[1],s$coefficients[3],s$coefficients[7])} else {
          o <- c(i,j,N,rep(NA,7))
        }
    } else {o <- NULL}
    return(o)
  },simplify=F))

}
,simplify=F))

toc = proc.time();
show(toc-tic);
```

This takes about 10 minutes on my machine.
You can imagine what happens when I need to handle a much larger (although more sparse) data matrix. I never managed to finish the calculation.

**Question**: do you think this could be done more efficiently?

The thing is I don't know which operations take more time (subsetting of `df`, in which case I would remove duplications of that? appending matrix data, in which case I would create a flat vector and then convert it to matrix at the end? ...).

Thanks!

---

**EDIT** following up from minem's post

As shown by minem, the speed of this calculation strongly depended on the way linear regression parameters were calculated. Therefore changing that part was the single most important thing to do.
My own further trials showed that: 1) it was essential to use `sapply` in combination with `do.call(rbind`, rather than any flat vector, to store the data (I am still not sure why - I might make a separate post about this); 2) on the original matrix I am working on, much more sparse and with a much larger nrows/ncolumns ratio than the one in this example, using the information on the `x` vector available at the start of each `i` iteration to reduce the `y` vector at the start of each `j` iteration increased the speed by several orders of magnitude, even compared with minem's original script, which was already much better than mine above.
I suppose the advantage comes from filtering out many rows a priori, thus avoiding costly `xna & yna` operations on very long vectors.

The modified script is the following:

```
set.seed(54321)
nr = 1000;
nc = 900;
dat = matrix(runif(nr*nc), nrow = nr)
rownames(dat) = paste(1:nr)
colnames(dat) = paste("time", 1:nc)
dat[sample(nr*nc, nr*nc*0.90)] = NA

df <- as.data.frame(dat)
df_ps <- names(df)
N_ps <- length(df_ps)

tic = proc.time()

naIds <- lapply(df, function(x) !is.na(x))
dl <- as.list(df)

rl <- sapply(1:(N_ps - 1), function(i) {
  if ((i-1)/10 == floor((i-1)/10)) {
    cat("\ni = ",i,"\n")
    toc = proc.time();
    show(toc-tic);
  }
  x <- dl[[i]]
  xna <- which(naIds[[i]])
  rl2 <- sapply((i + 1):N_ps, function(j) {
    y <- dl[[j]][xna]
    yna <- which(naIds[[j]][xna])
    w <- xna[yna]
    N <- length(w)
    if (N >= 5) {
      xw <- x[w]
      yw <- y[yna]

      if ((min(xw) != max(xw)) && (min(yw) != max(yw))) {

        # extracts from lm/lm.fit/summary.lm  functions
        X <- cbind(1L, xw)
        m <- .lm.fit(X, yw)

        # calculate adj.r.squared
        fitted <- yw - m$residuals
        rss <- sum(m$residuals^2)
        mss <- sum((fitted - mean(fitted))^2)
        n <- length(m$residuals)
        rdf <- n - m$rank
        # rdf <- df.residual
        r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss)
        adj.r.squared <- 1 - (1 - r.squared) * ((n - 1L)/rdf)

        # calculate se & pvals
        p1 <- 1L:m$rank
        Qr <- m$qr
        R <- chol2inv(Qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
        resvar <- rss/rdf
        se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
        est <- m$coefficients[m$pivot[p1]]
        tval <- est/se
        pvals <- 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
        res <- c(m$coefficients[2], se[2], pvals[2],
                 m$coefficients[1], se[1], pvals[1])
        o <- c(i, j, N, adj.r.squared, res)
      } else {
        o <- c(i,j,N,rep(NA,7))
      }
    } else {o <- NULL}
    return(o)
  }, simplify = F)
  do.call(rbind, rl2)
}, simplify = F)
out2 <- do.call(rbind, rl)

toc = proc.time();
show(toc - tic)
```

E.g. try with `nr=100000; nc=100`.

I should probably mention that I tried using indices, i.e.:

```
naIds <- lapply(df, function(x) which(!is.na(x)))
```

and then obviously generating `w` by intersection:

```
w <- intersect(xna,yna)
N <- length(w)
```

This however is slower than the above.

Comment: First of all, if you have only numeric data, I would really suggest to store as a matrix, not a data frame. Second, if your data is very sparse, why not store it as a sparse matrix?

Comment: OK, both these changes are possible. Do you think this will help speed up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Larges bottleneck is `lm` function, because there are lot of checks & additional calculations, that you do not necessarily need. So I extracted only the needed parts.
I got this to run in +/- 18 seconds.

```
set.seed(54321)
nr = 1000;
nc = 900;
dat = matrix(runif(nr*nc), nrow = nr)
rownames(dat) = paste(1:nr)
colnames(dat) = paste("time", 1:nc)
dat[sample(nr*nc, nr*nc*0.9)] = NA

df <- as.data.frame(dat)
df_ps <- names(df)
N_ps <- length(df_ps)


tic = proc.time()

naIds <- lapply(df, function(x) !is.na(x)) # outside loop
dl <- as.list(df) # sub-setting list elements is faster that columns

rl <- sapply(1:(N_ps - 1), function(i) {
  x <- dl[[i]]
  xna <- naIds[[i]] # relevant logical vector if not empty elements
  rl2 <- sapply((i + 1):N_ps, function(j) {
    y <- dl[[j]]
    yna <- naIds[[j]]
    w <- xna & yna
    N <- sum(w)
    if (N >= 5) {
      xw <- x[w]
      yw <- y[w]

      if ((min(xw) != max(xw)) && (min(xw) != max(xw))) { # faster

        # extracts from lm/lm.fit/summary.lm  functions
        X <- cbind(1L, xw)
        m <- .lm.fit(X, yw)

        # calculate adj.r.squared
        fitted <- yw - m$residuals
        rss <- sum(m$residuals^2)
        mss <- sum((fitted - mean(fitted))^2)
        n <- length(m$residuals)
        rdf <- n - m$rank
        # rdf <- df.residual
        r.squared <- mss/(mss + rss)
        adj.r.squared <- 1 - (1 - r.squared) * ((n - 1L)/rdf)

        # calculate se & pvals
        p1 <- 1L:m$rank
        Qr <- m$qr
        R <- chol2inv(Qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
        resvar <- rss/rdf
        se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
        est <- m$coefficients[m$pivot[p1]]
        tval <- est/se
        pvals <- 2 * pt(abs(tval), rdf, lower.tail = FALSE)
        res <- c(m$coefficients[2], se[2], pvals[2],
                 m$coefficients[1], se[1], pvals[1])
        o <- c(i, j, N, adj.r.squared, res)
        } else {
          o <- c(i,j,N,rep(NA,6))
          }
    } else {o <- NULL}
    return(o)
  }, simplify = F)
  do.call(rbind, rl2)
}, simplify = F)
out2 <- do.call(rbind, rl)

toc = proc.time();
show(toc - tic);
#  user  system elapsed 
# 17.94    0.11   18.44
```

Comment: Great, thank you @minem !
In fact, I later realised that there was an error in my code (`rep(NA,6)` should have been `rep(NA,7)`).
By other trials, I found that another big performance improvement can be obtained by collecting the indices of the non-`NA` records of the `x` data and use those to only look at the relevant records of the `y` data. I will post an edit later.

Comment: Actually, correction: doing what I said only improves the calculation for my larger set, not for this example. I suppose it's because my matrix is much more sparse. On the other hand, you're absolutely right, the `lm` part is what is killing this. As a test, I tried to change a few things in your script, and I can report the following. Original = 22 s. Recursive subsetting = 22 s. Two nested `for` loops instead of `sapply` = 20 s for the calculations alone BUT *much* slower to store the data (???) = ~10 min. `lm` as initially, but with `sapply` = ~10 min.

Comment: Thank you again, this looks useful! I know for a fact that if I append the values of `o` generated at each iteration to an external vaiable `Results`, this slows down the process ENORMOUSLY. There must be something fundamentally different between collecting the data that way rather than letting `do.call(rbind,` do the job on the output of `sapply`. I think this may be worth a separate post.